# how this tricky problem could be solved in python for creating subarray

Tags: python, algorithm, sub-array

write a program to create subset of given array  the value inside the array should be target value and length of array should be k

program that i have tried

```
arr = [1, 2, 8, 6, 4, 9, 5]
k = 3
target = 10
sub = []
res = []

for i in arr:
    sub.append(i)
    if len(sub) == k:
        if sum(sub) == target:
            res.append(sub[:])  
        sub.pop(0) 
print(res)
```

sample input:
`arr = [1,2,3,6,4,9,5]`
`k = 3`
`target = 10`
output =:
`[1,4,5]`

Comment: This is called the subset sum problem. See https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-find-all-solutions-to-the-subset-sum-problem-597f77677e45?gi=abefd565cc78

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, suggest a free page rather than a page that says: `The author made this story available to Medium members only. Upgrade to instantly unlock this story plus other member-only benefits.`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar So, don't suggest a link if it does not help. As simple as that.

Comment: Unironically why was OP downvoted? They actually have their attempt as well in the question. smh ‍♀️. Insert r/programmerhumor StackOverflow helpfulness meme here.

Comment: @SashSinha Very likely because the question is pretty common and OP has not demonstrated any research effort. They also didn’t say what their problem is.

Answer (score -1):

Use of [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) would be best here:

```py
from itertools import combinations

arr = [1, 2, 8, 6, 4, 9, 5]
k = 3
target = 10

subsets = [comb for comb in combinations(arr, k) if sum(comb) == target]
print(subsets)
```

This results in `list` of `tuple` not `list` to consider the chances of having other such combinations, despite the example showcasing only one.

If you want a custom `combinations` function you can create one by use of recursion:

```
def combinations(arr, k):
    if k == 0:
        return [[]]
    if not arr:
        return []
    head, *tail = arr
    return [[head] + combo for combo in combinations(tail, k - 1)] + combinations(tail, k)
```

Comment: This is extremely inefficient to the point of being impractical for large `n`. If there are `n` integers in the list, there exist `2^n — 1` subsets that need to be checked (excluding the empty set).

Comment: so how can we approach this problem without use of itertools.combination

Comment: @6004AbdulRahmanHarris check the update